# UIKIT - Dynamic CollectionView Cell Height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I have aimed to design a chat application. Therefore i've decided to use `UICollectionView` The trivial problem that you may know is resizing the cells height based on its content. E.g. if the chat bubble has 3 lines of content, it must expand its entire buble size for 3 lined textview or label.

As you may know, Apple has introduced a new feature for `UICollectionView`that let cells to sized dynamically. For achieving this behaviour, i have created my cell and used `ConstraintAnchor` (Basically Autolayout). When i create the cell from a nib, and use             `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)` everything works flawlessly. But i'm wondering that how i can use the feature without using **Nibs**

Here is my cell;

```
import UIKit

class ChatCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let textView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        tv.textColor = UIColor.black
        tv.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir-Book", size: 14)
        tv.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return tv
    }()

    let bubleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let image:UIImageView = {
       let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.image = UIImage(named:"2")
        return view
    }()

    let nameLbl:UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 15)
        view.text = "Alican Yilmaz"
        return view
    }()

    let dateLbl:UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.font = UIFont (name: "Avenir-Book", size: 11)
        view.textColor = UIColor.gray
        view.text = "5 days ago"
        return view
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1


        self.contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:300).isActive = true
        self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150).isActive = true

        addSubview(bubleView)
        addSubview(textView)

        bubleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bubleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bubleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bubleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bubleView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bubleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bubleView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bubleView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

As you see, i have created two constraints of my cell's contentView.
And used the code below in my `viewController`

```
 let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout =  {
            let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            return flowLayout
        }()
```

The result of the code seem like this, basically the automatic dynamic sizing with `estimatedItemSize` is not working.

[image: heres the picture of the result]

**SOLVED**

The main mistake was using `TextField` instead of `UILabel`
TextField is have no ability to multiline. 
And setted `textlbl.numberOfLines = 999` to achieve the right behaviour.

thanks in advance,

Comment: what about using boundingRect which will provide you width and height based on content.

Comment: Did you add the `UICollectionView` to your `UIViewController` and attach the `UICollectionViewDataSource` to the view controller?

Comment: yes i have added both and datasource to my vc.

Comment: This is the general way a collection view should be implemented: https://gist.github.com/sconewolf/ba92e47e5f1035efdaddf7c1ad8aee2b My advice is not to use `contentView`. Just align everything inside your cell to the cell's outer bounds and the cell should resize itself. And don't use `1` as your estimated size, give it something substantial like `50`. `1` breaks my autoresize, too.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but have just solved. My mistake was using TextField instead of UILabel. Editing the post for future developers.